# Empty grid on OpenStreetMap

Tags: android, osmdroid

I have only an empty grid in my activity. I added writing to external storage permission into my manifest:
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

My activity:

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_osm_map);

    if(isStoragePermissionGranted()){
        initMap();
    }
}

private void initMap(){
    MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.osm_map);
    final float scale = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    final int newScale = (int) (256 * scale);
    String[] OSMSource = new String[1];
    OSMSource[0] = "https://gps.4u.uz/";
    map.setTileSource(new OnlineTileSourceBase("USGS Topo", null, 1, 18, 256, "", OSMSource) {
        @Override
        public String getTileURLString(MapTile aTile) {
            return getBaseUrl() + aTile.getZoomLevel() + "/" + aTile.getY() + "/" + aTile.getX()
                    + mImageFilenameEnding;
        }
    });

    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

    MapController mapController = (MapController) map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(13);

    GeoPoint geoPoint = new LatLonPoint(41.63, 64.59);

    OverlayItem myLocationOverlayItem = new OverlayItem("Here", "Current Position", geoPoint);
    Drawable myCurrentLocationMarker = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_marker);
    myLocationOverlayItem.setMarker(myCurrentLocationMarker);

    final ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(myLocationOverlayItem);

    CustomOverLay overlays = new CustomOverLay(myCurrentLocationMarker, map, this);
    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem("Title", "Snippet", geoPoint);
    overlays.addOverlayItem(overlayItem);

    map.getOverlays().add(overlays);

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    map.setBottom(height);
    map.setRight(width);
    mapController.setCenter(geoPoint);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Log.d(TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
        initMap();
        //resume tasks needing this permission
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "permission dined after requesting");
    }
}

private static int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

As I found that permission request at runtime solved problem, I decided to add it. But it did not fix the problem.

And interesting things is that osmdroid file is located in internal storage, not external. I have cache.db and cache.db-journal files only. As I read, for osmdroid needs external storage for storing cache. I tried `OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.setCachePath(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());`. But there is no such a method. That is why I removed this line. And I could not use [this pitch](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_8VOmRyW664cFVUY3dvajlMNEU/view)

I am using osmdroid 4.2 version

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask for the permission before loading the map. If you do it afterwards, then it's too late. In your example, the map is created when the layout is inflated.

That said, I haven't test this work around, but basically after the permission is set, you can reset the map the tile provider using the following:

```
mMapView.setTileProvider(new MapTileProviderBasic(getContext()));
```

That may resolve your problem, otherwise, you have to ask for permission before the map view has been created.

Oh, that sample code, will probably require osmdroid 4.4

Comment: have you considered trying a newer version? that one is like 3+ years old and the library has a lot of newer features since then. Particularly with cache management.

Comment: For the grey grid, did you try zooming in?